# How to display a submodule on a github site?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I created a githiub site here: [My site](https://marvelous-software.github.io/)

I would like to add some pages from another repo so I entered the command:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/Marvelous-Software/FrameworkTelevision.git
```

then I tried to display a page but it doesn't work:

```
https://marvelous-software.github.io/FrameworkTelevision.git/Javascript/Lab%201.html
```

I have a repo for my web page and a repo for my school work.  I would like to keep them separate but display my school work on my site.  Is this possible?  Or do I have to duplicate files?

Comment: I can see https://marvelous-software.github.io/FrameworkTelevision/frameworktv.html so the submodule surely is there.

Comment: OK, thank you.  I was using the wrong url.  I used .../Frameworktelevision.git/... when i should've been using .../Frameworktelevision/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my url, it was incorrect.  The correct url is

```
https://marvelous-software.github.io/FrameworkTelevision/Javascript/Lab%201.html
```